# Android Signed Build - API's are not accessible in Mobile Network

Tags: android, api, cordova, ionic-framework, networking

We are having `API access issue for Android Signed build.`

We are building app through `Ionic Framework`.

**Below are some observations -**

```
-iOS and Android Un-Signed builds are working properly.

-In Browser  API's are accessible.

-But for Android Signed build,  API's are not accessible in Mobile Network.
```

Comment: for api access, which library you are using ?

Comment: Try checking proguard rules.

Comment: @HiteshTarbundiya Internal https API's are there on which we are facing issue.We are using Rest  API's.

Comment: Please mention your Network library and show proguard rules

Answer (score 0):

Add this: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` under `application` tag of your manifest and this should work.
It should look like this:

```
  <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
```

usesCleartextTraffic which is responsible for http calls is true by default but starting with Android 9 (Pie) Clear Text Traffic is disabled now.

Answer (score 0):

**After long research finally i resolved this.**

*Reason behind https requests fails only while releasing Android build APK is an issue with the SSL certificate when making https requests.if the `intermediate certificates` are not set up correctly then it would cause the request to fail on Android in release mode.*

**Below is the issue i found after checking https url in SSL URL checker.**

```
The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate
```